# FB comments working on site but moderation tool = empty

Tags: facebook, comments

I integrated FB comments on a static page. I can comment and see my comments, but I have problems with moderating comments in the moderation tool. There are no comments in the tool.

I have this code, which should help me to modearete:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<meta property="fb:admins" content="7675xxxxx" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxx5675551420" />
```

And in inside the body I have:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

        <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.example.com/demo" data-num-posts="10" data-width="900"></div>
```

What is the problem here?

By the way, how can I set it up, that also NON-Facebook Users can comment? I want to
allow anonymous comments. I see no settings for that?

thx

Answer (score 1):

Did you added your user account as moderator in http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments?
If not, try to add your user account in your application as moderator. Then see is it working.

Answer (score 0):

Please note moderation tool will be available only for non-admins's comments. You cannot moderate your (or other admins') comments.

Edit: Moderators can moderate only 'normal' users comments. Try commenting from a FB account which is not in the comment moderators list.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Why would admins not have access? It's that the point of being an admin?

Comment: Oops, moderators can obviously moderate comments. I fixed the typo in my post.